# Apache2の認証とキャッシュの関係

Tags: apache

自宅サーバーで、Apache2 + digest認証でWebサーバーを立ち上げています。
このサイトにChromeやFireFoxでアクセスすると、一日の初回はパスワードを要求するのですが、次回からは各ブラウザのキャッシュをクリアするまで、パスワードを要求せずに繋がってしまいます。

各ブラウザでは「このサイトのパスワードは記憶しない」設定にしているので、毎回パスワードを要求するはずと、思うのですが。

この動作は正常なのでしょうか？
問題があるとすれば、サーバー側でどのような設定が必要でしょうか？

Comment: 単にサーバー側に Cookie で「認証済み」を保持する機能が実装されているだけなのでは？　キャッシュの全クリアでなく Cookie の（部分）クリアで再認証要求するならそういうことで、正常動作っす。

Comment: Basic認証や Digest認証の有効期限はブラウザを閉じるまでです。ブラウザでF12キーを押して、開発者ツールを起動。送受信されるhttpヘッダーをみたら、何かわかるのでは？304 not modified だったりして。

Comment: 同じサーバーで他の簡易Webサーバーを動かしていて、こちらと動作が違っていたので勘違いしていました。簡易WebサーバーがCookieを使っていないだけだったようです。　　　ありがとうございました。